# Integral of a power combined with a Gaussian hypergeometric function

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I think the following is true for $k \ge 3$,
$$
\int_0^{\infty } (w+1)^{\frac{2}{k}-2} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{k},\frac{1}{k};1+\frac{1}{k};-w\right) \, dw
=
\frac{\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{k}\right)}{k-2}
.
$$
I have checked *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products* without any hit. Has anyone seen any formula that resembles the left hand side?

Edit:
This came up in my research when I tried to show another integral is equals the RHS. I was able to transform the integral into the LHS and it looked promising.  But eventually I used another proof. Anyway, it's still nice to see this direction also works.

Comment: I checked numerically for $3 \leq k \leq 500$ and it seems to be true. Now, how to prove it ???

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I do have proof but it's pretty long. So I am hoping there is a short one.

Comment: I would enjoy to see a proof of it (even if it is pretty long). If you want to contact me, my e-mail address is in my profile.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the hypergeometric function is incomplete beta function. One can use suitable integral representation (8.17.4 and 8.17.7 http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17) for incomplete beta function and then integrate by parts.

Comment: @Nemo. Thanks ! I totally forgot (age !!). Did you try to prove ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici that initial approach didn't work out, but I found another. Please see below.

Comment: Using Euler's integral representation of the hypergeometric function, you can show that the integral is related to an integral representation of the digamma function. The result then follows from the reflection formula for the digamma function.

Comment: @RandomVariable If you have time to write it down, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @RandomVariable I actually got it! Thanks for the clue! It's a nice and simple proof.

Comment: I posted my answer since I had already composed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the integral representation [15.6.6](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E6)
$$
\, _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{k},\frac{1}{k};1+\frac{1}{k};-w\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(1+1/k\right)}{2\pi i\Gamma\left(1/k\right)\Gamma\left(2/k\right)}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(1/k+t\right)\Gamma\left(2/k+t\right
)\Gamma\left(-t\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+1/k+t\right)}w^{t}dt,
$$
where the contour of integration separates the poles of $\Gamma\left(1/k+t\right)\Gamma\left(2/k+t\right)$ from the poles of $\Gamma(-t)$, interchanging the order of integration and calculating the integral over $w$
$$
\int_0^{\infty } (w+1)^{\frac{2}{k}-2} w^tdw=B(t+1,1-2/k-t)
$$
we get
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty } (w+1)^{\frac{2}{k}-2} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{k},\frac{1}{k};1+\frac{1}{k};-w\right) \, dw\\
&=\frac{1/k}{2\pi i\Gamma\left(2/k\right)}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(1/k+t\right)\Gamma\left(2/k+t\right
)\Gamma\left(-t\right)\Gamma(t+1)\Gamma\left(1-2/k-t\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+1/k+t\right)\Gamma\left(2-2/k\right)}dt\\
&=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{k}\right)}{2i(k-2)} \int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{dt}{t\sin (\pi/k-\pi  t) \sin \left(\pi/k+\pi  t\right)}.
\end{align}
The contour of integration here is so that the origin lies to the left. We see that the integrand is odd. Therefore if we choose the contour as $(-i\infty,-ir)\cup \Gamma_r\cup(ir,i\infty)$,$r>0$, where $\Gamma_r=\left\{|z|=r,\text{Re}~z>0\right\}$, the integrals along $(-i\infty,-ir)$ and 
$(ir,i\infty)$ cancel out. The integral along $\Gamma_r$ can be calculated in the limit $r\to +0$ and equals 
$$
\frac{\pi i}{\sin^2(\pi/k)}.
$$
Thus we get
$$
\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{k}\right)}{2i(k-2)} \cdot \frac{\pi i}{\sin^2(\pi/k)}= \frac{\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{k}\right)}{k-2}.
$$

Comment: Very nice, indeed. Thanks for providing this solution. $\to +1$.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment, we can alternatively use [Euler's integral representation of the hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type), along with a  well-known [integral representation of the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations).

We also need the [reflection formula for the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula).

$$\begin{align} I(k) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}(1+w)^{2/k-2} \, _2F_1 \left(\frac{2}{k}, \frac{1}{k}; 1 + \frac{1}{k};-w \right) \, dw   \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty}(1+w)^{2/k-2} \frac{1}{B \left(\frac{1}{k},1 \right)} \int_{0}^{1} x^{1/k-1}(1+wx)^{-2/k} \, dx \, dw \\ &= \frac{1}{k} \int_{0}^{1} x^{1/k-1}\int_{0}^{\infty} (1+w)^{2/k-2} (1+xw)^{-2/k} \, dw \, dx \\ &=\frac{1}{k} \int_{0}^{1} x^{1/k-1} \int_{1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{u-1}{x}+1 \right)^{2/k-2}u^{-2/k} \, \frac{du}{x} \, dx \\ &= \frac{1}{k}  \int_{0}^{1} x^{-1/k} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(u-1+x)^{2}} \, \left(\frac{u}{u-1+x} \right)^{-2/k} \, du \, dx \\  &= \frac{1}{k}  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{-1/k}}{x-1} \int_{1/x}^{1} v^{-2/k} \, dv \, dx \tag{1} \\ &= \frac{1}{k-2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{1/k-1}-x^{-1/k}}{1-x} \, dx \\ &= \frac{1}{k-2} \left(\psi \left(1- \frac{1}{k} \right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{k} \right) \right) \\ &= \frac{\pi}{k-2} \,  \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{k} \right)  \end{align} $$

This should hold for $k>1$, excluding $k=2$.

If $k=2$, then $(1)$ becomes $$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{-1/2}\log(x)}{x-1} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \psi_{1}  \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{4},$$ which is the limit of $\frac{\pi}{k-2} \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{k} \right)$ as $k \to 2$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Integral_representation

Comment: Thanks! I got the same proof using clues in your comment. I have to admit that I didn't really understand the previous one.

Comment: @ablmf then why did you accept it?